# Safely release a resource on a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a class similiar to:

```
class A{
    private:
    boost::shared_ptr< Foo > m_pFoo;
}
```

Instances of A are destroyed on the GUI thread where they **may** hold the last reference to a Foo.
The destructor for Foo is potentially long running, causing an undesirable pause on my GUI thread.
I would like for Foo to be destroyed on a separate thread in this case, Foo's are self contained and it is not critical
they get released immediately.

Currently, I use a pattern like this:

```
A::~A(){
    auto pMtx = boost::make_shared<boost::mutex>();
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> destroyerGate(*pMtx);
    auto pFoo = m_pFoo;
    auto destroyer = [pMtx,pFoo](){
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> gate(*pMtx);
    };

    m_pFoo.reset();
    pFoo.reset();
    s_cleanupThread->post(destroyer);
}
```

Essentially, capture it in a lambda and lock until released from the object.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  This just seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Better in what sense? What don't you like about this approach?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He's blocking his GUI thread through his expensive destructor. I assume he wants to avoid that.

Comment: Instead of spinning up a thread for each object to destroy, you could have a destroyer thread that just takes `shared_ptr`s from a queue and blocks when the queue is empty. I don't know if it would have any advantages.

Comment: @bku_drytt He's not, he's dispatching the destruction to a thread. But without knowing what he doesn't like about that approach, it's hard to know what he would consider better. If that's the actual code he's using, I can think of a lot of small improvements. If that's just meant to illustrate the approach he's using, I'd answer very differently.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My mistake. Creating a thread is expensive and he's multiplying that cost for every single `A` that he tries to destroy. I would suggest going with @MarkRansom's comment.

Comment: @bku_drytt That's assuming his issue with his present solution is the cost of creating the thread. Maybe he deletes very few such objects or the destructor is so expensive the cost of creating a thread is negligible. It's very hard to give a useful answer without understanding what he doesn't like about his current approach.

Comment: There actually is a thread dedicated to destroying the resource, I excluded it because I wrongly thought this was simpler.  My gripe with it is simply that this machinery seems more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The cost of the thread is negligible in my case.  I'm mostly worried about clarity.  I'm not a big fan of creating a mutex in a dtor either, but I want to ensure the thread destroys the resource after it has been released from A.  So mostly, I'm looking for something clearer that ensures destruction of a Foo after being released from an A.

Comment: Have the destructor that's called when the reference count goes to zero dispatch the thread to destroy the underlying real object.

Comment: Add a couple of documenting comments (it took me a few moments to comprehend your code, which is less than ideal) and this is a pretty decent solution, I would have thought. Do what Mark said, though, to make it substantially better. I can't think of any other changes I'd make.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The biggest advantage is that the queue can be bounded and pre-allocated... Creating _anything_ in a destructor is poor design, because creation operations in general can fail, and there is no sane way to handle failure in a destructor. Using a pre-allocated bounded-size work queue (with pre-allocated mutex + condition variable or semaphore or whatever) allows the destructor to avoid allocating anything.

Comment: _Instances of `A` are destroyed on the GUI thread where they hold the last reference to a `Foo`._ If `A` hold the last reference to `Foo`, why are you using `shared_ptr`s? They just incur needless overhead. Use `unique_ptr` inside `A` and regular pointers everywhere else.

Comment: @MarkRansom, putting the shared_ptrs on a queue to be read and discarded by another thread is an incomplete solution. There's no guarantee that the destructor decreases the reference count before that other thread and may end up doing the destruction itself instead of that other thread. Your solution relies on the scheduler letting the destructor run after posting the ptr on the queue before the other thread can read the queue, which is admittedly likely but not certain.

Comment: @bazza that's why I left a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom nwp's comment makes an interesting point -- if the pointers are always destroyed in one place, then it may be possible (and perhaps preferable) to use unique pointers with borrowing. If that's the case, then the unique pointer could be *moved* to the queue for the other thread to read and discard, thus guaranteeing deletion in the other thread.

Comment: I took the challenge and [implemented an asynchronous destruction service](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106422/asynchronous-object-destruction-service).  If this is what you were looking for, I can post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) has already suggested in the comments, you could use a dedicated destruction thread that takes the to-be-destructed objects from a work queue and then simply drops them on the floor. This works under the assumption that if you move away from an object, destructing the moved-away-from object will be very cheap.

I'm proposing a `destruction_service` class here, templatized on the type of object you want it to destroy. This can be any kind of object, not just shared pointers. In fact, shared pointers are even the most tricky ones because you'll have to be careful, that you only submit the `std::shared_ptr` for destruction if its reference count has reached one. Otherwise, destroying the `std::shared_ptr` on the destruction thread will basically be a no-op, except for decrementing the reference count. Nothing really bad will happen in this case, though. You'll only end up destroying the object on a thread that was not supposed to do it and therefore might be blocked longer than ideal. For debugging, you could `assert` in your destructor that you are not on the main thread.

I'll require that the type has a non-throwing destructor and move construction operator, though.

A `destruction_service<T>` maintains a `std::vector<T>` of the objects that are to be destructed. Submitting an object for destruction `push_back()`s it on that vector. The worker thread waits for the queue to become non-empty and then `swap()`s it with its own empty `std::vector<T>`. After leaving the critical section, it `clear()`s the vector thereby destroying all objects. The vector itself is kept around so it can be `swap()`ped back the next time reducing the need for dynamic memory allocations. If you're worried about the `std::vector`s never shrinking, consider using a `std::deque` instead. I'd refrain from using a `std::list` because it allocates memory for each item and it's somewhat paradox to allocate memory to destroy an object. The usual advantage of using a `std::list` as work queue is that you don't have to allocate memory in the critical section but destroying the objects is probably a low-priority task and I don't care if the worker thread is blocked a little longer than needed as long as the main thread stays responsive. There is no standard way to set the priority of a thread in C++ but if you want to, you could try giving the worker thread a low priority via the `std::thread`'s `native_handle` (in the constructor of `destruction_service`), given your platform allows this.

The destructor of the `destruction_service` will `join()` the worker thread. As written, the class is not copyable and not movable.  Put it in a smart pointer if you need to move it around.

```
#include <cassert>             // assert
#include <condition_variable>  // std::condition_variable
#include <mutex>               // std::mutex, std::lock_guard, std::unique_lock
#include <thread>              // std::thread
#include <type_traits>         // std::is_nothrow_{move_constructible,destructible}
#include <utility>             // std::move
#include <vector>              // std::vector


template <typename T>
class destruction_service final
{

  static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value,
                "The to-be-destructed object needs a non-throwing move"
                " constructor or it cannot be safely delivered to the"
                " destruction thread");

  static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value,
                "I'm a destruction service, not an ammunition disposal"
                " facility");

public:

  using object_type = T;

private:

  // Worker thread destroying objects.
  std::thread worker_ {};

  // Mutex to protect the object queue.
  mutable std::mutex mutex_ {};

  // Condition variable to signal changes to the object queue.
  mutable std::condition_variable condvar_ {};

  // Object queue of to-be-destructed items.
  std::vector<object_type> queue_ {};

  // Indicator that no more objects will be scheduled for destruction.
  bool done_ {};

public:

  destruction_service()
  {
    this->worker_ = std::thread {&destruction_service::do_work_, this};
  }

  ~destruction_service() noexcept
  {
    {
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard {this->mutex_};
      this->done_ = true;
    }
    this->condvar_.notify_all();
    if (this->worker_.joinable())
      this->worker_.join();
    assert(this->queue_.empty());
  }

  void
  schedule_destruction(object_type&& object)
  {
    {
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard {this->mutex_};
      this->queue_.push_back(std::move(object));
    }
    this->condvar_.notify_all();
  }

private:

  void
  do_work_()
  {
    auto things = std::vector<object_type> {};
    while (true)
      {
        {
          auto lck = std::unique_lock<std::mutex> {this->mutex_};
          if (this->done_)
            break;
          this->condvar_.wait(lck, [this](){ return !queue_.empty() || done_; });
          this->queue_.swap(things);
        }
        things.clear();
      }
    // By now, we may safely modify `queue_` without holding a lock.
    this->queue_.clear();
  }

};
```

Here is a simple use case:

```
#include <atomic>   // std::atomic_int
#include <thread>   // std::this_thread::{get_id,yield}
#include <utility>  // std::exchange

#include "destruction_service.hxx"


namespace /* anonymous */
{

  std::atomic_int example_count {};
  std::thread::id main_thread_id {};

  class example
  {

  private:

    int id_ {-1};

  public:

    example() : id_ {example_count.fetch_add(1)}
    {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    example(const example& other) : id_ {other.id_}
    {
    }

    example(example&& other) noexcept : id_ {std::exchange(other.id_, -1)}
    {
    }

    ~example() noexcept
    {
      assert(this->id_ < 0 || std::this_thread::get_id() != main_thread_id);
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }

  };

}  // namespace /* anonymous */


int
main()
{
  main_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  destruction_service<example> destructor {};
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
      auto thing = example {};
      destructor.schedule_destruction(std::move(thing));
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Barry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31292/barry) for [reviewing this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106422/asynchronous-object-destruction-service/106454#106454) and making some good suggestions for improving it. Please see [my question on *Code Review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106422/asynchronous-object-destruction-service/) for a less trimmed-down version of the code but without his suggestions incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

`A` should not be responsible for the destruction of the target of `m_pFoo`.  Destruction of the resource to which a `shared_ptr` points is the responsibility of the `shared_ptr`, so in my mind you shouldn't be micro-managing the thread on which destruction of the real object occurs inside `~A`.

Instead of implementing a new type of smart pointer that suits your needs, I think a good compromise here is to take the logic related to the deletion of the underlying object out of `~A` and move it to a custom deleter which you provide to the `shared_ptr` upon construction.  If you are happy with your current deallocation strategy, I think this is a satisfactory approach.  But I also agree with the others that you might want to investigate strategies which don't involve creating a new thread for every deallocation.

You can find the docs on how to provide a deleter to the `smart_ptr` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).  Scroll down to 'constructors taking a deleter' (also you might want to look up the documentation for the specific version of boost you are using).

Comment: An object is what it is, and if an owning class doesn't like the behaviour then who is responsible for modifying that behaviour? I think your right; class A's destructor shouldn't be having to worry about this, especially if class Foo is another part of the application's source code. If Foo is from some opaque unmodifiable class library then fiddling about like this in class A would be justified?

Comment: I said that deallocation of the underlying object is the responsibility of the `shared_ptr`.  I'm not suggesting that a good place for the fix is inside of `Foo` .  `Foo`'s deconstructor doesn't care about the CONTEXT in which it is called, it merely encapsulates the destruction of a `Foo`. `shared_ptr` is the type which is making assertion about the context in which `Foo` will be destroyed.  In this case, it says implicitly that destruction occurs on the same thread.  Therefore my proposed solution is to write a custom smart pointer, or provide a custom deleter to the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry I misunderstood. I tentatively submit that the interface presented by a class should include it's destruction characteristics as well as its public members. If there is a requirement for specific destruction characteristics (such as fast destruction) then the class should deliver it. Otherwise behaviour is partly implemented in the class, partly in its owner. That sounds wrong to me. To my mind putting the tricky bit in the destructor of Foo is probably the right place.

Comment: In contrast it's the kind of thing that could be mandated by a base interface class, but I don't really see how that would work in this case. A custom deleter might indeed be the best place to put that common code...